# Gauss-Seidel+SOR

Tags: performance, c, openmp, mpi

I am learning OpenMP+MPI hybrid programming. As an example I have chosen Gauss-Seidel+SOR. My implementation uses `MPI_THREAD_FUNNELED` style hybrid programming, overlapping of communication and computation, neighbourhood collectives, MPI IO etc. Based on my analysis and running many executions it seems to be correct (cannot guarantee however, since I am relatively new to this area).

I am looking for general comments and feedback for improving my OpenMP, MPI and hybrid programming skills. Additionally, I am particularly interested in learning the root cause of the following scalability issue:

Unfortunately MPI outperforms the OpenMP scalability on a single compute node:

[image]

- Hardware: 2x Xeon E5-2698 v3, 16 cores each
- Compiler: Cray C : Version 8.3.4
- Compiler Flags: `-h pragma=omp -h ipa5`
- MPI: cray-mpich/7.2.2
- Input functions: `f(x) = sqrt(x)` and `h(x) = 10 * sin(10 * x)`

My hypothesis is that this could be due to the ccNUMA architecture of the [Haswell-EP](http://www.anandtech.com/show/8423/intel-xeon-e5-version-3-up-to-18-haswell-ep-cores-/4) CPU. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-uniform_memory_access#Cache_coherent_NUMA_.28ccNUMA.29) says:

> ccNUMA may perform poorly when multiple processors attempt to access
>   the same memory area in rapid succession.

This is the case in my code. Additionally: If I have 8 OpenMP threads, then they are bound by `aprun` to cores which are all [connected by the same ring bus](http://images.anandtech.com/doci/8423/HaswellEP_DieConfig.png). When I increase to 16 cores the overhead for maintaining cache coherence increases and threads are bound to the cores of the first CPU and communication therefore has to go through the buffered switches. In the case of 32 threads even through QPI. The MPI version will require a lot less cache synchronisation, since the data is spread among several processes. Note that in the OpenMP case the complete data fits into one memory page.

```
#include "functions.h"
#include <mpi.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <sys/param.h>
#include <float.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <omp.h>

void iteration_loop(double* u, const int right_most, const int right_ghost, const int left_most, const int left_ghost);
void redblack(double* u, int right_most, int right_ghost, int left_most, int left_ghost);
void cacheFunctions(const int start, const int end, const int N_local);
void writeresult(const int N_local, const double* u);
double step(double* u, const int n);
extern double f(double x);
extern double r(double x);

static double * ff;
static double * rr;

#define N 6000 /* number of discretization points */
static const double h = 1. / (N - 1); /* discretization step */
static const int MAX_ITER = 1000000; /* iteration limit */
static const int TERMINATION_DETECTION_INTERVALL = 8000;
static const double EPSILON = 0.0000001; /* convergence criterion */
static const double THETA = 0.9; /* relaxation factor for SOR */

static int world_rank, world_size; /* MPI */
#define ndims 1 /* one dimensional Cartesian coordinate system */
static const int peridos[ndims] = {0}; /* grid is not periodic  */
static int dims[ndims] = {0}; /* division of processors in a Cartesian
                                 0 allows MPI_Dims_create to override element */
static MPI_Comm COMM_GRID; /* Cartesian communicator */
static int my_coords[ndims]; /* Cartesian of process */

/* MPI_Request objects for non-blocking communication */
static MPI_Request neighbor = MPI_REQUEST_NULL;
static MPI_Request reduce = MPI_REQUEST_NULL;

static double start, end; /* used to calculate runtime */


////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    /* This code requires MPI_THREAD_FUNNELED. Quit if not met. */
    int provided_thread_support;
    MPI_Init_thread(&argc, &argv, MPI_THREAD_FUNNELED, &provided_thread_support);
    if (provided_thread_support == MPI_THREAD_SINGLE) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Provided only MPI_THREAD_SINGLE\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &world_rank);
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &world_size);

    /* Divides processors in a Cartesian grid. */
    MPI_Dims_create(world_size, ndims, dims);
    /* Create communicator with Cartesian topology */
    MPI_Cart_create(MPI_COMM_WORLD, ndims, dims, peridos, 0, &COMM_GRID);
    MPI_Cart_coords(COMM_GRID, world_rank, ndims, my_coords);

    /* data distribution, number of cells assigned to processor */
    int N_local = ((N - 2 + dims[0] - my_coords[0] - 1) / world_size);
    /* two additional memory cells are required for ghost cells / boundary condition*/
    int MEM_local = N_local + 2;

    /* Indices */
    int left_ghost = 0; /* Index of left ghost cell */
    int left_most = 1; /* Index of left most local cell */
    int right_ghost = N_local + 1; /* Index of right ghost cell */
    int right_most = N_local; /* Index of right most local cell */

    /* Time measurement */
    MPI_Barrier(MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    start = MPI_Wtime();

    /* Cached r and f */
    rr = malloc(N_local * sizeof (double));
    ff = malloc(N_local * sizeof (double));
    cacheFunctions(1, right_most, N_local);

    /* Allocate initial guess (all zero) */
    double* u = calloc(MEM_local, sizeof (double));
    if (u == NULL) {
        perror("calloc");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    iteration_loop(u, right_most, right_ghost, left_most, left_ghost);

    /* Time measurement */
    MPI_Barrier(MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    end = MPI_Wtime();

    writeresult(N_local, u);

    if (world_rank == 0) {
        printf("\n\nExecution time: %f\n", end - start);
    }

    /* Cleanup */
    free(u);
    free(rr);
    free(ff);

    MPI_Finalize();
    return (EXIT_SUCCESS);
}


////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

/* Caches results of f(x) and r(x) in ff[] and rr[] respectively */
void cacheFunctions(
        const int start,
        const int end,
        const int N_local) {
    for (int n = start; n <= end; ++n) {
        const double x_n = (my_coords[0] * N_local + n) * h;
        ff[n] = f(x_n);
        rr[n] = r(x_n);
    }
}

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

/* Perform SOR until termination condition is met.  */
void iteration_loop(
        double* u,
        const int right_most,
        const int right_ghost,
        const int left_most,
        const int left_ghost) {

    /* Maximum deviation from current and previous iteration */
    double maxdelta = 0.0;
    double oldmaxdelta = DBL_MAX;

    /* For iteration loop control */
    bool terminate = false;
    int iter;

    /* Iteration loop */
#    pragma omp parallel default(shared) private(iter) firstprivate(terminate)
    for (iter = 0; iter < MAX_ITER; ++iter) {
        /* Breaking Out of iteration loop  */
        if (!terminate) {
            /* Communicate ghost cells */
#            pragma omp master
            {
                redblack(u, right_most, right_ghost, left_most, left_ghost);
            }
            /* Update cells 2 to right_most - 1 which are independent
               of ghost cells  */
#            pragma omp for schedule(static) reduction(max:maxdelta)
            for (int n = 2; n <= right_most - 1; ++n) {
                double delta = step(u, n);
                maxdelta = MAX(maxdelta, delta);
            }

#            pragma omp master
            {
                /* Wait until ghost cells are completely communicated */
                MPI_Wait(&neighbor, MPI_STATUSES_IGNORE);
                /* Update cells dependent on ghost cells */
                double delta;
                delta = step(u, left_most);
                maxdelta = MAX(maxdelta, delta); /* only visible to master, acceptable */
                delta = step(u, right_most);
                maxdelta = MAX(maxdelta, delta); /* dito */
            }

            /* If reduction of termination condition was initiated in previous
             * iteration. */
            if ((iter - 1) % TERMINATION_DETECTION_INTERVALL == 0) {
                /* Wait until reduction of global maximum deviation has completed */
#                pragma omp master
                {
                    MPI_Wait(&reduce, MPI_STATUSES_IGNORE);
                }
                /* All threads need to wait for master to complete MPI reduction
                 * and they need to see the result in oldmaxdelta in order to
                 * know if they should break the loop */
#                pragma omp barrier
                /* If maxdelta of previous iteration is smaller than EPSILON, terminate */
                if (oldmaxdelta < EPSILON) {
                    if (world_rank == 0) {
                        printf("[%d] breaking after %d of %d iterations\n", omp_get_thread_num(), iter, MAX_ITER);
                    }
                    terminate = true;
                }
            }
#            pragma omp master
            {
                /* Decides if termination detection should take place in this iteration */
                if (iter % TERMINATION_DETECTION_INTERVALL == 0) {
                    //printf("2) iter=%d, oldmaxdelta=%.9f, maxdelta=%.9f \n", iter, oldmaxdelta, maxdelta);
                    /* Save maxdelta to oldmaxdelta in order to overlap reduction with computation */
                    oldmaxdelta = maxdelta;
                    /* Perform reduction to find global maximum deviation in current iteration */
                    MPI_Iallreduce(MPI_IN_PLACE, &oldmaxdelta, 1, MPI_DOUBLE,
                            MPI_MAX, COMM_GRID, &reduce);
                }
            }
            /* master resetts maxdelta, after initiating Iallreduce */
#            pragma omp master
            {
                maxdelta = 0;
            }
            /* all threads need to wait until maxdelta has been updated */
#            pragma omp barrier
        }
    }
}

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

/* Perform SOR on cell  */
double step(double* u, const int n) {
    const double last_u = u[n];
    u[n] = (u[n - 1] + u[n + 1] - h * h * ff[n]) / (2. - h * h * rr[n]);
    u[n] = u[n] + THETA * (u[n] - last_u);
    return fabs(last_u - u[n]);
}

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

/* Perform redback communication. */
void redblack(
        double* u,
        const int right_most,
        const int right_ghost,
        const int left_most,
        const int left_ghost) {


    int counts[] = {1, 1};
    int sdispls[] = {left_most, right_most};
    int rdispls[] = {left_ghost, right_ghost};
    MPI_Ineighbor_alltoallv(&u[0], counts, sdispls, MPI_DOUBLE,
            &u[0], counts, rdispls, MPI_DOUBLE, COMM_GRID, &neighbor);
}

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

/* Write result to file. */
void writeresult(const int N_local, const double* u) {
    /* Global index of processor's first cell */
    const int global_offset = world_rank * ((N - 2) / world_size) + MIN(world_rank, (N - 2) % world_size) + 1;
    /* Length of output line */
    const int LINE_SIZE = 19;
    /* Allocate memory for every output line and \0 terminator */
    char * buf = malloc(N_local * LINE_SIZE + 1);
    /* Write output to buffer */
    for (int i = 1; i <= N_local; ++i) {
        const double x_n = (global_offset + i) * h;
        sprintf(buf + (i - 1) * LINE_SIZE, "%f %+f\n", x_n, u[i]);
    }

    /* MPI IO */
    MPI_File fh;
    MPI_File_open(MPI_COMM_WORLD, "pde.out", MPI_MODE_CREATE | MPI_MODE_WRONLY, MPI_INFO_NULL, &fh);
    if (world_rank == 0) {
        /* Master writes boundary condition, since this is not contained in
         any local cell */
        MPI_File_seek(fh, 0, MPI_SEEK_SET);
        char * boundery0 = "0.000000 +0.000000\n";
        MPI_File_write(fh, boundery0, LINE_SIZE, MPI_CHAR, MPI_STATUS_IGNORE);
    }
    MPI_File_seek(fh, global_offset * LINE_SIZE, MPI_SEEK_SET);
    MPI_File_write(fh, buf, (N_local * LINE_SIZE), MPI_CHAR, MPI_STATUS_IGNORE);
    MPI_File_close(&fh);
    free(buf);
}
```

Comment: I would agree with your suspicion on the NUMA. I think it is pretty rare to see an OpenMP benefit beyond a single NUMA domain. Also, the advantage of a hybrid parallelization often only gets visible for large node counts, so a single node measurement might be a little misleading. Still, 4 OMP threads per MPI Rank and 8 ranks per node, seem to be a good option on your system. So I'd conclude your assessment is correct .

Answer (score 1):

Overall the code is well written, but it will be difficult to maintain. There are at least 2 functions that are too complex, `main()` and `iteration_loop()`. I suggest breaking up both functions by having sub-functions that perform some of the actions. This is especially true in `iteration_loop()` given the level of indentation in that function. Smaller functions are easier to read, write, debug and maintain because they are easier to understand. In this case smaller functions might also make the code easier to profile to find the bottlenecks.

## Inconsistent Testing of Allocated Memory

There are 4 instances of memory allocation in the code; only one of these tests whether the allocation was successful. All 4 instances should be tested.

In modern high-level languages such as C++, memory allocation errors throw an exception that the programmer can catch. This is not the case in the C programming language. While it is rare in modern computers because there is so much memory, memory allocation can fail, especially if the code is working in a limited memory application such as embedded control systems. In the C programming language, when memory allocation fails, the functions `malloc()`, `calloc()` and `realloc()` return `NULL`. Referencing any memory address through a `NULL` pointer results in **undefined behavior** (UB).

Possible unknown behavior in this case can be a memory page error (in Unix this would be call Segmentation Violation), corrupted data in the program and in very old computers it could even cause the computer to reboot (corruption of the stack pointer).

To prevent this **undefined behavior** a best practice is to always follow the memory allocation statement with a test that the pointer that was returned is not NULL.

## Avoid Global Variables

Some of the variables in this program may indeed need to be global due to the multi-processor architecture, but there are others such as `start` and `end` that can be defined within local scope.

It is very difficult to read, write, debug and maintain programs that use global variables. Global variables can be modified by any function within the program and therefore require each function to be examined before making changes in the code. In C and C++, global variables impact the namespace and they can cause linking errors if they are defined in multiple files. The [answers in this Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/484635/are-global-variables-bad) provide a fuller explanation.

## Code Organization

Function prototypes are very useful in multi-file projects, but within the file that contains `int main(int argc, char** argv)` it is generally better to put `main()` last and not have function prototypes unless there is some kind of dependency between functions. There are many reasons for this organization within the file, but the best reason is to reduce the amount of code that needs to be written. Reducing the amount of code in the file reduces the possible number of bugs that can be introduced in the code. Reducing the number of function prototypes also makes it easier to maintain the code because the code will only need to be maintained in one place if the function parameters change.